# Why does the function require p,q to be found?

Tags: functions

I have the following question,
[image]

Why is it important to find (a) since its possible to solve the questions without it ?

also they found the range to be $f(x)>3$ but isnt the range already given as $f(x)>2$

Comment: many of these questions are slightly connected yet can be solved independently. its good to see that a same function can have multiple ways of looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good for you if you can do the other parts without doing part (a) first.  But it does potentially make the other parts easier.  For instance, as long as $q\neq 0$, the representation  $f(x)=p+\frac{q}{x-2}$ makes it pretty easy to see that $f(x)$ is one-to-one (since it is a composition of a bunch of functions that are clearly one-to-one: $x\mapsto x-2$, $x\mapsto 1/x$, $x\mapsto qx$, and $x\mapsto p+x$).

As for the range, I would assume that in the context of this question "range" means "image", rather than "codomain".  That is, the range is the set $\{f(x):x\in A\}$, which might be smaller than the entire set $B$.  The set $B$ such that $f$ is defined to be a function $A\to B$ is then called the "codomain", rather than the "range".

Comment: well it has to be smaller since $x>2$ right ? but why isnt the range then defined as $f(x)>= 3$ since 3 is also a valid value

Comment: What value of $x$ do you plug in to get $f(x)=3$?

Comment: Oh i think i got it mixed up I thought they where changing the $x>2$ but since f(x)=3 has no solutions the range must lie above it right?